# Java - public static double not returning

Tags: java, static, public

I'm trying to learning Java from zero. I have an exercise that after reading it all over again I can't find why doesn't work. Researching on Google and StackOverflow returned to zero results...

Main objective is to translate dollars to pesetas by just multiplying by a number. I have to use two functions and call them on "main".

My problem is that "convertToPesetas" isn't taking the returned double of "askDollars". Can someone hand me a rope?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Converter
{
    public static void main(String[] args){        
        askDollars();
        convertToPesetas();
    }       

    public static double askDollars(){
        System.out.println("Type the quantity of dollars:");
        Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
        double dollars= keyboard.nextDouble();   
        System.out.println("Dollars: "+dollars);
        return dollars;        
    }
    public static double convertToPesetas(double dollars){        
        double pesetas = pesetas*166.386;        
        System.out.println(dollars+ "€ equals to: "+pesetas+" pesetas");
        return pesetas;
    }

}
```

Comment: That doesn't even compile and yet you think not including the error message makes for a good question?

Comment: look _really_ closely to the right-hand side of the first line in your `#convertToPesetas` method. Additionally, you have to use the values returned from your `#ask...` method, and pass them to the `#convert...` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're not storing or supplying that value:

```
askDollars();
convertToPesetas();
```

Save the returned value in a variable and pass that variable to the next method:

```
double dollars = askDollars();
convertToPesetas(dollars);
```

Note: `convertToPesetas` also returns a value.  You don't seem to need it to do that.  *But*, you could use that if you take your design in a different direction.  As an academic exercise for your next step, consider three methods:

1. One which asks for the user input.
2. One which converts the dollars value to the pesetas value.  This has *no* input or output, just a method argument and a return value.
3. One which prints the output.

Each method would do exactly one, simple thing.  And when you have this, you'll find that the second method is free to easily be moved to other objects, etc. because it's entirely independent and not coupled to the user interface in any way.

Comment: That still discards the result of `convertToPesetas()`

Comment: @JimGarrison: It does, yes.  Though the logic of the program doesn't seem to need that anyway.

Comment: This is what fixed my code! I didn't know how to pass the variable to the next method. I knew that convertToPesetas(); had to be pass as an argument (I wrote bash scripts where I needed to do this, but I didn't have to make an variable assignament).

""" As an academic exercise for your next step, consider three methods:"""
My exercise requires the three methods you mentioned, and I already made them, it works everything.

Thank you very much, excuse my english too.